# PL/SQL error: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows ORA-06512:

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to enter a student id from the students table to get the decision of whether they passed or failed from the module_grades table but i keep getting that error when i enter the student id can anyone help, thanks
Here is my code:

```
set serverouput on
DECLARE
Student Students.Sid%type:='&sid';
decision MODULE_GRADES.MDECISION%type;
BEGIN
SELECT MDECISION INTO decision FROM MODULE_GRADES
WHERE Sid = Student;
IF
(decision = 'Pass')
Then
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('You got'||Decision||' congratulations');
END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the error because the `SELECT INTO` returns at least two rows. In PL/SQL a `SELECT INTO` [must return exactly one row](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#LNPLS551), no more, no less.

When using `SELECT INTO`, you should query the table by a combination of conditions that guarantees uniqueness -- usually a primary key. In your case you are probably missing a filter or you have an anomaly in the data.

If you're expecting cases where there could be more than one row, you should either:

- use a loop:

  ```
  FOR cc IN (SELECT DECISION FROM MODULE_GRADES WHERE Sid = Student) LOOP
     -- do something
  END LOOP;
  ```
- or catch the exception

  ```
  BEGIN
     SELECT MDECISION INTO decision 
       FROM MODULE_GRADES
      WHERE Sid = Student; 
     -- do something
  EXCEPTION
     WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
        -- do something else
  END;
  ```